# How to change a dropdown to a text box for barcode scanning into a field

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an Appmaker form to create a record that includes a many to one relation to another table. By default, the form creates a dropdown to select the related record from a list. This works fine, but I need to barcode scan (or type) the item name rather than select it.

When I change the dropdown to a text box and bind it to the related table, it greys out and becomes unusable when I preview it. (I get a circle with a line through it when hovering over.)

When I keep both the dropdown and the textbox on the same form, I can select a record from the dropdown and it populates the textbox. After that, the textbox becomes editable and works as desired.

How can I remove the dropdown and make the text box editable?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you bind the textbox to a relational field it is looking for a record not just a value. 
My thought is you are going to want to create a text box where you enter/scan in the value and leave it unbound. then in probably the onValueChange event write a script to query the item in the related table that you are trying to relate and set that equal to the field you are trying to edit.I don't know that this code will work haven't tested it but should get you going in the right direction:

```
  var ds = app.datasources.Parts;
  ds.query.filters.Part._equals = newValue;
  ds.load(function() {
    if (ds.item === null) {
      alert("Part not found!");
      widget.root.descendants.FieldPart.value = null;
    }
    else {
      widget.root.descendants.FieldPart.value = ds.item;
    }    
  });
```